# Background image does not extend to full width on tablet

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

[image]I am attempting responsive design.

Link here: http://truewizard.com.au/buildzone/v2/

I have attached an image of the issue from my nexus.

I think it may have something to do with this line of code:

```
 <meta name="viewport" 
  content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />
```

Any ideaS?

CSS:
                body,html {
                padding:0px;
                margin:0px;
                height:100%;
                }

```
            body {
            background:#0f0f0f;
            font-family: "Calibri", Georgia, sans-serif;
            font-size:14px;
            line-height:30px;
            color:#bdbdbd;
            }

            a {
            text-decoration:none;

            }

            /* Clearfix */

            .clearfix:after {
                content: ".";
                display: block;
                clear: both;
                visibility: hidden;
                line-height: 0;
                height: 0;
            }

            .clearfix {
                display: inline-block;
            }

            html[xmlns] .clearfix {
                display: block;
            }

            * html .clearfix {
                height: 1%;
            }


            /*Header*/

            #title_bar #logo {
            float: left;
            }

            #title_bar #phone-number {
            float: right;
            }

            #banner {
            background:url(images/banner.jpg) no-repeat;
            }

            #banner .container {
            position:relative;
            }

            .learn_more {
            font-size:18px;
            display:inline-block;
            padding-right:15px;
            background:url(images/learn_more_arrow.png) no-repeat right center;
            }

            .learn_more a {
            color:#63d1ff;
            }



            /*service Tabs*/

            .tab_body {
            position:relative;
            }

            .tab_body img {
            margin:0 auto;
            display:block;
            position:relative;
            top:25%;
            }


            /*Main Wrap*/

            #main_wrap {
            padding-top:40px;
            }

            #quote_form {
            width:385px;
            height:409px;
            background:url(images/quote_form.jpg) no-repeat;
            padding:90px 40px 0 30px;
            }

            #quote_form input {
            width:276px;
            height:27px;
            background:#1f1e1e;
            border:1px solid #282828;
            color:#bdbdbd;
            }

            #quote_form textarea {
            background:#1f1e1e;
            border:1px solid #282828;
            width:272px;
            height:200px;
            }

            #quote_form #quote_form_submit {
            color:#bdbdbd;
            background:#3c3c3c;
            cursor:pointer;
            }

            #quote_form fieldset {
            border:0;
            }

            #quote_form td {
            padding:2px 0 2px 0;
            }

            #quote_form .quote_form_label {
            padding-right:20px;
            }

            .highlight_text {
            color:#25aae1;
            font-size:18px;
            }

            #main_wrap .highlight_text {
            margin:0;
            }


            h3 {
            color:#fff;
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            font-size:14px;
            }

            .tab_title {
            text-align:center;
            height:37px;
            padding-top:5px;
            }

            #testomonials_box {
            height:433px;
            clear:both;
            }

            #testomonials_bg {
            height:331px;
            background:url(images/testomonials_box.jpg);
            }

            #clients_say {
            height:62px;
            padding-top:40px;
            }

            /*slideshow*/

            #slides {
            position:relative;
            height:331px;
            }

            .slides_container {     
            height:273px;

            }

            .slides_container div {     
            display:block;

            }

            .testomonial_text {

            margin-top:40px;
            text-align:center;
            }

            .testomonial_text p {
            text-align:right;
            padding-right:50px;
            }


            .pagination {
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            height:11px;
            overflow:hidden;
            width:84px;
            margin:0 auto;
            }

            .pagination li {
            float:left;
            padding:0 5px 0 5px;
            list-style:none;
            }

            .pagination li a {
            background:url(images/pagination.png) no-repeat;
            width:11px;
            height:11px;
            display:block;
            padding-top:15px;
            }


            /*footer*/

            #footer {
            background:url(images/footer_bg.gif) repeat-x;
            height:400px;
            }

            @media screen and (min-width: 960px) {

                    #banner {
                    height:613px;
                    }

                    #refreshing_approach {
                    margin:50px auto 10px auto;
                    }

                    #desc {
                    color:#fff;
                    font-size:18px;
                    width:640px;
                    padding-left:60px;
                    }

                    .container {
                    width:960px;
                    margin:0 auto;
                    }

                    #title_bar {
                    height:67px;
                    background:#1f1f1f;
                    }

                    #service_tabs {
                    height:200px;
                    position:absolute;
                    /*top:413px;*/
                    top:413px;
                    }

                    #web_design_tab {
                    width:210px;
                    height:200px;
                    margin-right:40px;
                    float:left;
                    }

                    #web_design_tab img{


                    }

                    #print_design_tab {
                    width:210px;
                    height:200px;
                    margin-right:40px;
                    float:left;
                    }

                    #ecommerce_tab {
                    width:210px;
                    height:200px;
                    margin-right:40px;
                    float:left;
                    }

                    #internet_marketing_tab {
                    width:210px;
                    height:200px;
                    float:left;
                    }

                    .tab_title {
                    width:210px;
                    background:#1f1f1f;
                    }

                    .tab_body {
                    height:158px;
                    width:210px;
                    background:#2f2e2e;
                    }

                    #left_box {
                    float:left;
                    width:460px;
                    }

                    #right_box {
                    float:right;
                    width:460px;
                    padding:10px 0 30px 0;
                    }



                    .testomonial_text {
                    width:960px;
                    font-size:40px;
                    line-height:50px;
                    }



            }


            @media screen and (min-width: 760px) and (max-width:959px) {

                    #banner {
                    height:960px;
                    width:100%;
                    }

                    #refreshing_approach {
                    margin:80px auto 10px auto;
                    max-width:100%;
                    }

                    #desc {
                    color:#fff;
                    font-size:18px;
                    width:640px;
                    padding-left:60px;
                    }

                    .container {
                    width:760px;
                    margin:0 auto;
                    }

                    #title_bar {
                    height:67px;
                    background:#1f1f1f;
                    }

                    #service_tabs {
                    height:547px;
                    position:absolute;
                    top:500px;
                    width:680px;
                    margin:0 auto;
                    padding:0 40px 0 40px;
                    }

                    #web_design_tab {
                    width:320px;
                    height:200px;
                    margin-right:40px;
                    float:left;
                    margin-bottom:40px;
                    }

                    #print_design_tab {
                    width:320px;
                    height:200px;
                    margin-right:0px;
                    float:left;
                    }

                    #ecommerce_tab {
                    width:320px;
                    height:200px;
                    margin-right:40px;
                    float:left;
                    margin-bottom:40px;
                    }

                    #internet_marketing_tab {
                    width:320px;
                    height:200px;
                    margin-right:0px;
                    float:left;
                    }

                    .tab_title {

                    width:320px;
                    background:#1f1f1f;
                    }

                    .tab_body {
                    height:158px;
                    width:320px;
                    background:#2f2e2e;
                    }

                    #left_box {
                    padding:0 40px 0 40px;
                    }

                    #right_box {
                    padding:0 40px 0 40px;
                    }

                    #quote_form {
                    margin:50px auto;
                    }

                    .testomonial_text {
                    width:760px;
                    font-size:35px;
                    line-height:35px;
                    }


            }
```

Comment: Could you post your CSS?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stretch it use background-size:100% 100%. If it's not proportional with the original image then use one of the sizes on 'auto' - background-image:100% auto;

Comment: I need some backwards compatibility, from what I understand background-size is CSS3 so I'm guessing it will only work in the latest set of browsers

Comment: `background-size` will work with all modern browsers, but everything else is a desktop, so you can use that `media-query` or IE hacks to make it work everywhere else.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size - here you can see all the supported browsers

Answer (score 1):

I know you're not asking for a javascript fix, but here is a sample I made that addresses what you need:

[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Dq7VR/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('html').css({
        "background-size": $(window).width() + "px" + " " + $(window).height() + "px"
    });
    $('html').show();
});

$(window).resize(function () {
    $('html').css({
        "background-size": $(window).width() + "px" + " " + $(window).height() + "px"
    });
});
```

It grabs the screen size on load and resize and adjusts the background to fit.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the background image is on a div not in the body, and have a fixed height.
Consider using width: 100% and/or a display(block, or inline with float), on the #banner

Answer (score 0):

The background image is too small to get fit in the screen, you need a bigger image of do repeat of the background image like :

```
background: url(images/banner.jpg) repeat;
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you already tried to use responsive solutions such as AnyStretch: https://github.com/danmillar/jquery-anystretch ?

This issue happens because the device is trying to preserve the aspect ratio.

Comment: Was a long time ago now, I fixed the problem, though I can't really remember how I did now :(, thanks anyway